# wx.ListCtlr grouped list

Tags: python, wxpython, listctrl

Does anyone know a solution to group my listctlr list? I have read about the groupListView but it is not really python based solution and less supported by python.
Unfortunately I did not find solution. Thanks for any idea, suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ObjectListView](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ObjectListView/1.2)
 The `GroupListView` supports arranging rows into collapsible groups.

Comment: It would be fine, but unfortunately I got the following exception:

File "/usr/local/lib/wxPython-3.0.0.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-3.0-osx_cocoa/wx/_controls.py", line 4635, in RefreshItems
    return _controls_.ListCtrl_RefreshItems(*args, **kwargs)
wx._core.PyAssertionError: C++ assertion "lineTo < GetItemCount()" failed at /BUILD/wxPython-src-3.0.0.0/src/generic/listctrl.cpp(1923) in RefreshLines(): invalid line range

I am on os x environment, I have found details about that: 

http://sourceforge.net/p/objectlistview/bugs/2/

But it didn't help. Are there any idea regarding to this?

Comment: Ok this is interesting. Which version do you use? Otherwise I got this exception when I try to run the example codes from the release package.